# Page showing just one of two custom fields on front end

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created some custom fields (blocco_contenuto and schede_prenotazione) for the product page of a website. My problem is just one of two is showing on the front end.
Below the link to a product page of the site:
https://www.montecatinieventi.net/shop/citta-del-natale-2019/

If you inspect the page you will see just blocco_contenuto is displayed. The other should appear right before the three columns with the tree types of hotels.

This is the code I use:

```php
<div class="product-single-content">
<?php 

$blocchi_di_contenuto = get_field('blocco_contenuto');
$schede_prenotazione = get_field('schede_prenotazione');

if (!empty($blocchi_di_contenuto)) { 
?>
    <div class="blocchi_wrapper">
<?php 

if (have_rows('blocco_contenuto')) {
    while(have_rows('blocco_contenuto')) {
        the_row(); 

?>
        <div class="<?php the_sub_field('classe') ?>">
<?php   

        $titolo_ = the_sub_field('titolo');
        if (!empty($titolo_)) { 
             the_sub_field('titolo') 
        } 

?>
             <div class="contenuto">
<?php 
        the_sub_field('contenuto') 
?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
    }
}
</div>
<!-- blocchi_wrapper -->
```

I'm a bit lost on this because I can't really find what's wrong, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But where is your css for those?

Comment: Also, the website is huge, please provide better explanation as to where the hidden div is. I dont have time to be looking forever

Comment: Hi, The other should appear right before the three columns with the tree types of hotels.

Answer (score 0):

in the code you supplied you put the content  of **"schede_prenotazione"** in the variable **"$schede_prenotazione"** but then you never use it again. so there is no reasoin for it to be displayed.

if it's a single data field you should display it with

```
echo $schede_prenotazione;
```

where you want it to appear.

if it's a repeater you should use the "have rows" function like

```
if (have_rows('schede_prenotazione')){
    while (have_rows('schede_prenotazione')){
        the_row();
    }
}
```

and then display the subfields within the brackets (i can't show an example because i don't know what the sub fields are).

Comment: I tried to add that, after the same function for blocco_contenuto and the output is no content at all, in the sense that all the other fields don't show as well. Weird.